How can we have weekly capacity for internal Service Resource?
We want to have a field on Service Resource object to define weekly capacity for each resource.
How can we incorporate this logic of weekly capacity through Work Rule in Scheduling Policy, as we need to use Scheduling Policy to show available slots on the website.
